# Fetching Video data from YouTube's video list API bringing wrong data

Tags: reactjs, youtube, axios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API's parameters, there's a list of required parameters in which one of the filter parameters has to be picked for the data to be fetched. The parameters are `chart`, `id` and `myRating`, which I don't need any as I don't have the video IDs and no access to users ratings (I just want to fetch videos).
So what I do is to pick the `chart` and set it to `mostPopular` like so:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  
  onSubmitForm=async (text)=>{

    const key= {my actual key}
    
    const response = await axios.get( 
      'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos',
      {
        params: {
          part:'snippet',
          maxResults :10,
          type: 'video',
          chart:'mostPopular'
          key,
          q: text, 
        },
      })
 }
```

However, this returns only the 10 most popular videos which *are devoid* of anything I put in my `text` search term.
So in summary, it throws up an error if I don't use one of the filter parameters `chart`, `id` and `myRating`, and when I do use `chart`, it brings up popular videos not related to my search query. How do I navigate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to acknowledge that the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint has no `q` parameter. You may well confuse it with the request parameter [`q`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) of another API endpoint, that of [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Consequently, you have two orthogonal options: either use `Videos.list` queried with parameters `chart=mostPopular` in tandem with [`regionCode`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#regionCode) and [`videoCategoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#videoCategoryId). Or, otherwise, use `Search.list` queried with parameter `q` as you need.